# Objective C unarchive array of custom nsobjects

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, xcode, nsobject

So I have a custom NSObject class called model.  My problem is that I have an array of these custom model objects that has already been archived so they can be used in my arrays and nsuserdefaults. I am stuck on how to unarchive them.  My archive method works as I have a separate method that calls the archive method and saves the results to an array in nsuserdefaults.  I have a method that works fine to unarchive individual model objects but I need to know how to unarchive every archived object in the array.

Archive method:

```
   - (void)writeFavoriteObject:(Model *)favorite
{
    NSData *favoriteObject = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:favorite];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:favoriteObject forKey:kNSUSERDEFAULTSCAR];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
```

Unarchive method:

```
- (Model *)readFavoriteObjectWithKey:(NSString *)key
{
    NSData *favoriteobject = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:key];
    Model *favorite = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:favoriteobject];
    return favorite;
}
```

My attempt to unarchive and use my array:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath      *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"NewsCell";
    CarViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier    forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    defaultsarray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    defaultsarray = [defaults objectForKey:@"favoritesarray"];

    FavoriteCar = [defaultsarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    FavoriteCar = [self readFavoriteObjectWithKey:kNSUSERDEFAULTSCAR];



    cell.CarName.text  = FavoriteCar.CarModel;
    cell.CarImage.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL  URLWithString:FavoriteCar.CarImageURL relativeToURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://pl0x.net/image.php"]]]];

    //Accessory
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    cell.layer.borderWidth=1.0f;
    cell.layer.borderColor=[UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    cell.CarName.layer.borderWidth=1.0f;
    cell.CarName.layer.borderColor=[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;

    return cell;
}
```

My tableview displays the correct number of rows because I can get an accurate count, but the cell just repeats the first Object.  A possible solution would be some kind of method like `[FavoriteCar readFavoriteObjectWithKey:kNSUERDEFAULTSCAR];` so each object would be unarchived.  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: It is very inefficient to unarchive every time in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` - you should unarchive in a method  like `viewDidLoad`.  You can then set a breakpoint and check the data in the array

Answer (score 0):

My Assumptions:

```
- (void)writeFavoriteObject:(Model *)favorite
{
    NSData *favoriteObject = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:favorite];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:favoriteObject forKey:kNSUSERDEFAULTSCAR];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
```

here favorite is a single object every time u r archiving the favorite object with same key and every time the old favorite object replacing by new favorite object so the last one will be the only one favorite object archived.

So Instead of sending single favorite object to above method send array which holds all favorite object and archive it .

Comment: Thankyou for your response.  I have figured out the archiving part by using a button which calls the archive method and then saves an array to nsuserdefaults.  What I'm left with is an array with multiple unarchived objects as I can see through NSLog.